# Loop through array of nested objects to check empty string es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of nested objects:

```
const array =[
 { 
    "id": 1,
    "time": { 
       "timezone": "2021-09-22T05:36:22.484Z"
       "city": "Perth"
       "country:: "Australia
       "date": "2021/10/10"
    }
 },
 {
   ​"id": 2,
   ​"time": { 
       "timezone": ​"2021-10-22T03:25:26.484Z"
       "city": ""
       "country: "Americas"
       "date": "2021/10/10"
    }
 },
 {
   ​"id": 3,
   ​"time": { 
       "timezone": ​"2021-09-27T02:43:26.564Z"
       "city": ""
       "country: ""
       "date": "2021/10/10"
    }
 }];
```

I want to check each value in the time object to see if there exists an empty string without having to have multiple || statements.

What I have tried using lodash:

```
if(array.find((k)=> _.isEmpty(k.timezone)) || array.find((k)=> _.isEmpty(k.city)) || array.find((k)=> _.isEmpty(k.country)) || array.find((k)=> _.isEmpty(k.date))) {
//do something
 
 } else {
//do something else
 }
```

This seems to do the trick but trying to find a succinct and cleaner way to do this as there could be more values in the time object, preferably in es6.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `.some` of the `Object.values` of any of the `time` subobjects includes the empty string.

```
if (array.some(
  k => Object.values(k.time).includes('')
)) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```